# Change page url in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have my own CMS system, but I can't make a code in `.htaccess` file.

I want redirect from `http://example.com/?page=forum` to `http://example.com/forum`...
I don't know, how do it...

I tried the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /projects/cms/

RewriteCond ?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L,NE]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

But it didn't work.
Sorry for my bad English, thanks for Code.

Comment: RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING} page=([^&]+) [NC]

Comment: @JackubKučera - Where did you put splash58's suggestion?

Comment: Here: RewriteCond ?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]

Comment: You can't make .htaccess file, but you show the code from a .htaccess file... confusing!

Comment: what  do you receive now?

Answer (score 0):

The comment [splash58](/users/4804629/splash58) posted is correct - you need to check the `QUERY_STRING` for the presence of `page=<something>`, like this:

```bsh
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L,NE]
```

Your file should now look like this:

```bsh
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /projects/cms/

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

If it is still not working, then you need to ensure that `mod_rewrite` is enabled on your server, and that `AllowOverride All` is set in your server or virtual host configuration. See this for more information on how to do so: http://tildemark.com/enable-htaccess-on-apache/

Comment: But i have problem with other folders...

I have /projects/cms/admin/ and here it didn't work. It redirect me to /projects/cms/pagename...

Comment: It does that because of the `RewriteBase`. You need to create another `.htaccess` file in the `admin` folder containing the first condition and rule, only you must set the `RewriteBase` to `/projects/cms/admin/`